# How could I automatically agitate water by blowing warm air over its surface?

Tags: airflow, evaporation

I want to increase the evaporation rate in a tank by blowing warm air over the surface of the water in the tank; this will (hopefully) agitate the water, increase the airflow in the tank, and maybe heat the tank slightly. How could I do this?

The main goal here is not to heat the tank, but to agitate the water in the tank. The fan/device/whatever works has to be somewhat small, in addition, and it should blow without human assistance.

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: Depending on the tank size , there are various types of aquarium equipment that could help .

Answer (score 1):

If your primary objective is to increase evaporation, you are more likely to decrease the temperature of the water rather than increase it.

If you can accept the reduction of temperature, consider that many otherwise-stagnant ponds use fountains to provide for evaporation and agitation to prevent algae growth. If your tank is large enough, a small aquarium pump and nozzle could provide additional exposure to the air. Depending on the current surface area, a number of such nozzles would further increase the flow.

If a mini-fountain is unacceptable, a "dribble" pipe around the perimeter of the tank or criss-crossing the surface above the tank will also provide for increased exposure and evaporation.

More details added via edit may be useful.

Comment: Why decreasing the temperature of the water leads to increase the evaporation?